# Making an Object (I think object) linkable - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

Trying to figure out how to make my thing.name a clickable URL that redirects to thing. Seems easy enough, but I cannot figure it out. Maybe I shouldn't be using the `link_to` to achieve this?

Currently I have the following

```
 <% thing.each do |thing| %>                                      
                      <tbody>                          
                        <tr>
                          <td><%= thing.name %></td>
                          <td><%= link_to 'Show', thing %></td
```

Trying to figure out how to make thing.name a URL, so that I can remove `<td><%= link_to 'Show', thing %></td`

Answer (score 1):

Typically it would be

```
link_to thing.name, thing_path(thing)
```

`thing_path` here would be a dynamic form of an [URL Helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html). To work properly, the route to thing in your config/routes.rb file must be properly declared. See the [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more details on that.

Comment: Right, but i'm looking to remove the 'Show' text and have the name of the thing (thing.name) the link.

Answer (score 0):

i don't really get what you wanna achieve but do you mean you want to make something like url `www.blabla/thing/name"`, if you wanna do it you would like to use gem [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)